# How do I execute my Python Script with Argument?

Tags: python, arguments

I have a text file. But I dont want to input that file in my python script directly. I want to run my python script from command line with argument which is my text file. The command line that I want is : $Python.exe script.py C:/user/text_file.txt . Then, the text file will put in the infile (in python script) and do the process.

this code return me printing all words in the script. Looks like this :
[[], [], ['im', 'po', 'rt', ' '], [], ['de', 'f ', 'ma', 'in', '(a', 'rg']]

```
 import sys

    def main():
        infile = sys.argv[0]
        Array = ["f4", "f3", "f2", "f1"]
        with open(infile, "r") as input_file:
            output_list = []
            for rec in input_file.read().splitlines():
                rec = rec[:-3]
                FBlist = [rec[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(rec), 2)]
                output_list.append(FBlist)
                print(output_list)



    main()
```

I modify my question. I misunderstanding with the previous problem.

Comment: You'll need to use the full path of the file.

Comment: But I am not sure for the path, each time to execute the python script, the path file is different @ThierryLathuille

Comment: Then how do you know where your file is supposed to be? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I mean, the file in external path of the python script

Comment: The way you explained it until now, it sounds like "someone puts the file in some random directory on my computer and I have no way to know where". In this case, there's not much we can do to help you find it. Or is your question "How do I find a file knowing only its name"?

Comment: I thing the second one is correct. I only now the name, but I dont know the path. @ThierryLathuille

Comment: So do you want to search the whole drive for the file? What is the expected behavior if there is more than one file of the same name?

Comment: @Job Your comment on Jane's answer say something completely different. So, please take time to think about how to formulate your question accurately and edit it.

Comment: I updated the question @ThierryLathuille

Comment: the sentence `path of the file is not fixed, and in different path with my python script` is VERY confusing, try to use different words to describe the same meaning. It could mean multiple things and it is not clear what is required at all.

Comment: @Job what happens if you change `Input_file = open ("Test.txt", "r")` to `Input_file = open (r"C:\User\X\Data\Test.txt", "r")` ?

Comment: It works if i put the full path of the Test.txt file. But the problem is, how if I dont put the full path? @reportgunner

Comment: you have to put the path **somewhere**. why don't you want to put the path anywhere ?
If you have two files with the same name at different paths, how can your program determine which is the one you mean?

Comment: @reportgunner I modify my question. I was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
file = open('yourFilePathHere', 'r')
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

Comment: But, my the path file is not consistent (I dont know the path exactly)

Comment: how is the filename generated?  I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I have text file (1.txt) . The path of the file is unconsistent place and each time run the python code, the path file of the text file is different.

Comment: what is causing the filename to change?

Comment: The name of the text file is not change, but the path of the file will change.

Comment: what is causing the path to change?

Comment: This is the case : first, I put my python script and text file in this path : C:\User\X\Data.
So, If I want to run my python, I have to go to C:\User\X\Data> python Pyscript.py 
The problem is. If I want to run my python script in C:\User> python Pyscript.py . The text file is not found.

Comment: @Jane isn't he looking to put the path of the script in the %PATH% environment variable so he can then run it from anywhere ?

Comment: @reportgunner I think so. But I dont know exactly about it

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly not the path of the file changes. Just the directory where you start your python script from changes. The file isn't found in the directory
C:\User because i doesn't exist in this directory. You just have to use the absolute path of the file like mentioned above:

```
file = open('C:\User\X\Data\1.txt', 'r')
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

Or if you execute your Python Script from the same directory ( C:\user) every time you can use the relative path instead:

```
file = open('X\Data\1.txt', 'r')
print(file.read())
file.close()
```